# How to find out what enclosure a disk belongs to?

Tags: linux, udev, disk, scsi

`lsscsi` tells me that I have a number of disks and enclosures.

I can use `$ ls /sys/class/enclosure/6:0:10:0/ArrayDevice*/device/scsi/disk` to get a listing of all the scsi addresses of disks under the 6:0:10:0 enclosure.

I can correlate that list with `lsscsi` output to see where each disk is.

But surely I don't need to write a script to automate this. Is there a tool like `udevadm` or `sg_ses` or something that can do this task for me?

Answer (score 1):

Is it an answer?

```
[root@hard-3 ~]# ls -ldF /sys/block/sda/device/enclosure_device\:0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 июл 26 18:25 /sys/block/sda/device/enclosure_device:0 -> ../../../../../../port-1:0:4/end_device-1:0:4/target1:0:1/1:0:1:0/enclosure/1:0:1:0/0/
[root@hard-3 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install sg3_utils (sg3-utils on debian) package. `lsscsi` command will help you identify the bus id of the enclosure. You could query `sg_ses -p 7 /dev/bsg/<busid>`

here is an example:

```
[0:0:64:0]   disk    HGST     HUHAJLGALLLAAAAA  A384  /dev/sdbl
[0:0:65:0]   enclosu HGST     4U60G2_STOR_ENCL 0101  -
```

Once you have the bus ID:

```
sg_ses --page=7 /dev/bsg/0:0:65:0
```